# SlidesJS Auto height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow

I've ran into an issue here using the SlidesJS slider for a wordpress site with multiple slideshows being loaded via ajax to the same page ( not running at the same time ) with the AutoHeight value. I managed to get the AutoHeight to work by option, and it actually works, it just doesn't work with the first image of the slideshow. The first image doesn't appear at the first time loading. When clicking next, or waiting till the Slideshow does this automatically everything works with the other images.

I guess that's because when the slider first time loads the height is 0 ?!

I can't use a fixed CSS height for the slider, I tried using the max-height value, which didn't work, it will fallback on a fixed height for the slider this way. height auto in css doesn't work as well obviously. Does anybody know a way to work around this problem ? It is just the first image that doesn't load properly.

I will paste the CSS and Javascript of the code bellow

```
 initializePortSlider=function(){
    if($().slides) {

        var portSliderPreloader = $('#portfolio-slider').attr('data-loader');

        $("#portfolio-slider").slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: portSliderPreloader,
            play: 5000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            autoHeight: true, 
            container: 'portfolio-slider-wrap',
            effect: 'fade',
            next: 'gallery-next',
            prev: 'gallery-prev',
            crossfade: true,
            generatePagination: false
        });

    }
    };
    initializePortSlider();
```

The CSS for the slider

```
#portfolio-slider {
position: relative;
width: 588px;
line-height: 1;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;}

#portfolio-slider .portfolio-slider-wrap {
position: relative;
width: 588px;}

.portfolio-slider-wrap a,
.portfolio-slider-wrap img {
display: block;
width: 588px;
height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get this right when the slideShow loads only the first image gets height 0.

you can fix this several ways:

css:

```
.portfolio-slider-wrap img:first-child {
   height: auto or 100%;
}
```

if that wont work you can do this the javscript way:

```
$('.portfolio-slider-wrap').find('img').each(function(i, obj){
  if (obj.clientHeight <= 0){
      obj.style.height = obj.offsetParent.clientHeight + 'px';
  }
});
```

add this code right after the init of the slide show.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, I tried both, didn't work.. the javascript will apply the height of the first image to the ones coming after. The CSS, I tried before and you have the problem that the first image doesnt load. What worked though is this ".portfolio-slider-wrap div:first-child { min-height:500px; }" the problem here that it is a pretty bad solution since some sliders just have two images which exceed 800 pixels, some are just 400 pixels ( height ) I'm not sure if this is bull what I'm asking, since I'm very unexperienced when it comes to Javascript, but would it be possible to have.

Comment: a different slide speed for the first child image via javascript ? That way I could just work around it by placing a white 1x1 pixel that just disappears after a second, sliding to the next picture

Comment: tell me exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Since, the Autoheight for the first child image of the slider doesn't appear. But it is possible to have incluence on first image via css with "img:first-child" is it also possible to have inluence on the first-child via Javascript to make it fadeout after a second or two or slide with a different speed ? this way it wouldn't matter the auto height doesnt work and I could bypass it by using a loading gif or something similar as a first image for each slider as a dummy

Comment: You can use jquery to insert image before the first one: $('.portfolio-slider-wrap img').first().before('<img src="" alt="" />');

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a great help here. I will use this solution. But ( I'm not asking this because I'm a jquery n00b but also to figure out whats possible and how it works for the future ) if the value ".first()" effects the first image (if it does ), is it possible combine it with "play: 5000" or the effect "effect: 'fade'" from the slideoptions ?

Comment: yes you can use css3 for that image or just add that style through the javascript code. use css 3 transitions read about it on google. And btw no problem was happy to help if you got more question you can ask me anytime.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still playing with the SlidesJs, but I'm about to replace it, which is going to be a load of work. I still think this post will be helpful for others because I found a few posts where they had the same problem with the SlidesJs, which is unfortunate because the Slider is actually super easy to implant

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the slider height to image height on each scroll.
This solution worked for me.

#slides is the id of div i'm using where all img are placed.

`// other option for slidesjs,`

```
callback: {
          loaded: function(number) {
            // Use your browser console to view log
       jQuery('#slides').height(jQuery('.slidesjs-control img:nth-child(1)').height());
            console.log('SlidesJS: Loaded with slide #' + number);
          },
          start: function(number) {
            // Use your browser console to view log
            console.log('SlidesJS: Start Animation on slide #' + number);
          },
          complete: function(number) {
            // Use your browser console to view log
            console.log('SlidesJS: Animation Complete. Current slide is #' + number);
  jQuery('#slides').height(jQuery('.slidesjs-control img:nth-child('+number+')').height());
          }
```